# Test validation that makes sure record is associated to records only owned by parent with spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, testing, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have model Category which has and belongs to many Packages. When a user creates a Posting in a Category, it must belong to a Package that is in its category.

Here's the code for the custom validator:

```
class PackageValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    record.errors[:package_id] <<
      I18n.t('errors.messages.package.not_in_category') unless
      record.category.packages.include? record.package
  end
end
```

This works great and all, but it breaks all my rspec tests (with factory_girl) because factory_girl creates a new Package for each Category and Posting I build/create with it.

Here's my factories:

```
factory :category do
  sequence(:name) {|n| "Parts#{n}"}
  sequence(:slug) {|n| "parts#{n}"}
  packages {[FactoryGirl.create(:package)]}
end

factory :posting do
  title 'Foo'
  body 'Bar'
  category
  package
end

factory :package do
  sequence(:name) {|n| "Basic#{n}"
  price 0
  photos 5
end
```

How can I make it all play nicely together?

Comment: Can you do something in the posting factory like set package to `category.packages.first`, possibly in an `after(:build)` hook?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. My validator still broke the shoulda matchers, but that's because it assumes that Posting is built with a Category. Adding `return if record.category.nil?` at the beginning of the `PackageValidator#validate` method fixed that. I already have a validation that ensures the presence of a Category, so that should work fine.

Comment: Can you convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the package to `category.packages.first` in an `after(:build)` hook.